# Laravel call to undefined method getOriginalContent after upgrade to 5.7

Tags: laravel

So,
I upgraded my Laravel project from 5.6 to 5.7.13. I had this code in a function of a controller as a file delivery method (which used to work fine):

```
public function sendFile(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'path' => 'required|string|min:1|max:256',
    ]);

    return Storage::download($request->path);
}
```

but now I am getting:

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse::getOriginalContent()
```

I have checked for the existance of a file. In fact, this works fine:

```
    if(Storage::exists($request->path)) return 'true';
```

I have not edited any of the vendor files. So, what is the problem here?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is the controller method being called, and it's not a different route that matches? Have you run `composer update` on the affected host? What version of PHP are you running on?

Comment: It looks like the code is trying to figure out the original content of the file before downloading it. Is that a local or remote storage?

Comment: @TravisBritz Yeah the issue was what bigface suggested. I made sure that this was the function being called. But the issue was with the telescope.

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez This was on local storage. The problem was with the Laravel telescope. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed laravel/telescope? This issue has been officially fixed. You need to update laravel/telescope.
https://github.com/laravel/telescope/commit/e4f5c0dd07970fb73fbf79cfa96316b7f91560cf